# Issue of same jar in multiple aar and using to build into single android application

Tags: android, jar, android-multidex

My scenario is like i'm using same jar in multiple aar and integrating  into single project. How to avoid the jar duplication issue.Multiple dex files issue.

Comment: Why you need to do that. You can simply use the created aar in new one and make transitive = true;

Comment: i couldnt get you.kindly explain me in detail with codes

Comment: Option 1: Create one aar with the required jars. Then use the created aar in the next one and make transitive = true (for the added aar).

Option 2: Otherwise try to exclude it when adding it to the dependency

Comment: that option doesn't suits my scenario. I need any means to minimize the duplicated jar at application level

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid duplication of aar files in multi project build android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610332/how-to-avoid-duplication-of-aar-files-in-multi-project-build-android)

Comment: Creating the same dumb question every day until someone gets tired and answers it ? You're going to be waiting a long time ...

Comment: what is your problem sir. I have doubts . I'm asking. Kindly if you know the answer, answer otherwise dont downgrade the questions.

Comment: My problem is you are duplicating your own question in complete disregard of the effort to keep things tidy, as indicated in the help section. Downvoting question is there for those who think the question is bad, and that's my case, your revenge votes won't change that.

Comment: @saranya : Try to exclude it

Comment: @Teril okay I will try

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand but maybe this will help.

If you're using gradle for every dependency you can define a closure and use `exclude` property. That way you can define groups, modules, etc, that are to be ignored.

It is often used to solve dependency conflicts in libraries.

Discussion in gradle forums: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-exclude-transitive-dependency/2119/2